# How should I make multiple many to many relationships between the same two models?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database

If I had `Book` and `Author` and the relationship between can exist as `MainAuthor` and `AssistantAuthor`. There could be multiple instances of `MainAuthor` and `AssistantAuthor`. What are the tradeoffs between making two separate join tables, or adding a field in the join table that represents the relationship on whether it's `MainAuthor` or `AssistantAuthor`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how much do you think the business model will change in the future.

The benefit of two separate relationship is that it looks cleaner, simpler. If you want the main authors you use one relationship; if you want the asistants you use the other one. Another benefit is that it's cheaper to adopt this solution.

The benefit of a single relationship with a "type" field is flexibility over time. What happens if next month you want to add a third or fourth type of author? For example: a legal adviser, or a collaborator? The same single relationship should be able to accommodate more types easily.

Bottom line: if you think the relationship is stable and won't change, go for the first one; if you prefer to add flexibility, you could adopt the second one that is a little bit more expensive.